# What is syslog and how can I tackle problems by using it?

Tags: syslog

Browsing through many Linux forums, I found that many Ubuntu geeks solve issue using `syslog`. They analyze it, and post the answer.

What is this syslog, and how can it help me solve problems with my system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many software packages that can provide system logging. Ubuntu is using the package `rsyslog`. Its configuration files are located in `/etc/rsyslog.conf` and `/etc/rsyslog.d/*`. The configuration files define which system messages to log, which directories to store messages, and which files to record different portions of system messages. As with the majority of Unix and Linux, the system log files are recorded in the files located in the directory, `/var/log/`.

By examining these files, we can learn what is happening with the software on the system. For example, `auth.log` records user authentication events, `boot.log` records boot events, `syslog` records all messages except authentication events (in the default configuration).

To examine a log file in real time: `tail -f /var/log/syslog`

To find cron-related messages: `grep cron /var/log/syslog`

To learn more about system logging from the command line:

```
apropos syslog
```

This command, apropos, will try to return relevant manual pages for the term `syslog`.

It will return a reference for `rsyslogd` and its configuration files.

There is also a good [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syslog) on the topic.